Why do commentators assume Psalm 74 wasn't written by David's Asaph?
The psalm makes generic references to the destruction of the sanctuary/temple. The psalm attributes it to Asaph and David's Asaph was called a prophet, so why do commentators assume this is a descendant of Asaph rather than a prophetic psalm? Is there something I'm missing in the title information that clues them in? It is frustrating when historical-critical scholars draw conclusions that leave out a supernatural possibility and then I'm left wondering if they're seeing something I'm missing from the "data."

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the community of users to maintain the integrity of the site. Up-voted +1.

According to Ed Gallagher,  Associate Professor of Christian Scripture at Heritage Christian University, here is an explanation as to why critical scholars think the superscriptions of the Psalms a not reliable:

The two main problems with taking the superscriptions as inspired are
(1) that they were clearly added after the composition of the psalm
and (2) that the LXX and Dead Sea Scrolls attest alternative
superscriptions. Even Futato (p. 119) considers the superscriptions
later additions to the text, based on three reasons:


the superscriptions are composed in the third person, thus appearing
editorial rather than authorial

the superscriptions vary according to the MT, LXX, and 11QPsa (Dead Sea Scrolls)

Psalm 14 is identical to Psalm 53 except for the superscriptions, so at least one of the superscriptions had to have come later.


Regarding Psalm 74 specifically, the editors of the NABRE introduce this poem as:

A communal lament sung when the enemy invaded the Temple; it would be
especially appropriate at the destruction of Jerusalem in 587 B.C.
Israel’s God is urged to look upon the ruined sanctuary and remember
the congregation who worshiped there (Ps 74:1–11). People and
sanctuary are bound together; an attack on Zion is an attack on
Israel.

Conclusion: Critical scholars tend to understand the psalms a liturgical works composed by priests for worship purposes, not as prophecies (although some psalms do contain avowedly prophetic material). They think it is more likely that later compilers attributed certain psalms to people such as David and Asaph than that these men actually wrote them. Rather than being part of the original text of the Bible, these scholars believe the superscriptions are similar to the psalm numbers - the work of later scribes rather than part of what should be considered done under the inspiration of the Holy Spirt.

Thank you for the thoughtful and thorough response. Based on what you said, do you know what information those scholars draw that conclusion from? That the Psalms were basically liturgical in nature rather than personal reflections or smaller/ musical prophetic utterances?

@MaxPalmer... they analyze the content. Many scholars who accept the superscriptions as authoritative also recognize the liturgical nature of some of the psalms supposedly written by David, but they see David as a prophet whom God inspired to create poems that we later used as liturgies.

Here is one explanation: " From David’s personal prayer to God, he grew in devotion to liturgical prayer. The prayers of the king led him to a reverence for the prayers for and by God’s people. As such, he sought to codify and formalize the various prayers of God’s people. As he collected them, he also added his own prayers to God, which added to the depth and beauty of the collection. The codification of these prayers has come to be called the Book of Psalms." https://cruxnow.com/commentary/2023/12/king-davids-spiritual-legacy-rests-in-the-book-of-psalms

as far as specifics:  Ps 4 says: "For the leader; with stringed instruments. " Several others likewise give instruction to the singers and musicians, but it was the priests, not the king, who governed temple worship. Even Ps 23 speaks of dwelling in the House of the Lord forever. (the temple was the dwelling place of priests; the king lived in his palace even after the temple was built). Perhaps the clearest example is Ps 122 where David supposedly says "I rejoiced when they said to me,
“Let us go to the house of the Lord.”'  (how could they say this when the Temple was not yet built?)
